# Exibir somente div filha com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Preciso atacar a div `comentarioPost` e fazer somente a div do respectivo post ser exibida.
Eu simulei alguns comentários para testar, depois eles virão do banco com as outras informações.
Como faço isso com jQuery?
Eu deixei a div `display none` no CSS e preciso exibir quando alguém desejar visualizar os comentários.

Em outras palavras, estou precisando dar um `display block` somente na div da respectiva postagem, é como se fosse uma rede social e cada post tem seus comentários, atualmente eu consigo exibir a div mas acabam todas ficando visiveis, eu preciso exibir somente a div do respectivo post. Eu estou exibindo por PHP mesmo usando um laço do `while`. No caso preciso exibir somente a div `comentarioPost` quando eu clicar no link `comentarioPost` que fica dentro da tag a `linkComentario`.

Desta forma eu consigo exibir todas as divs, mas eu queria exibir somente a div filha do post.

```
$(".comentarios").click(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(".comentarioPost").css("display", "block"); 
});
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
require_once '_funControllers/postagemLinhaDoTempo.php';
require_once '_funControllers/exibePostagensLinhaDoTempo.php';
require_once '_funControllers/select-Dados-User-Logado.php';
?>
<?php do { ?>

    <div class="postagens" id="div<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>">
        <div class="topPostar"><img class="imgChat" src="uploads/<?php echo exibeImg($exibePostagensAssoc['id_user']) ?>"/><a href="perfil?user=<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>&nome=<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['nome_user'] ?>" title=""><?php echo "<p style='margin-top:6px;float:left;margin-left:10px;'>$exibePostagensAssoc[nome_user]</p>" ?></a>
            <div class="botaoPainel">
                <?php botaoDelete($dadosLogado['U_id'], $exibePostagensAssoc['id_user']) ?>
            </div><!--fecha a div botaoPainel-->
        </div><!--fecha a div topPostar-->
        <div class="meioPostagens">
            <div class="contornoPostagens">
                <!--Verifica se o campo nome na tabela img_postagens tem algum valor ou se é diferente de ''-->
                <?php if (isset($exibePostagensAssoc['nome']) and ( $exibePostagensAssoc['nome'] != '')) : ?> 
                    <a href="home?post=<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>&postagem=<?php echo imprimeComTracos($exibePostagensAssoc['mensagem_post']) ?>" title="">
                        <img class="imgPostar" src="<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['caminho'] . $exibePostagensAssoc['nome'] ?>"/>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <p style="text-align: left"><?php postagem($exibePostagensAssoc['mensagem_post']) ?></p>
            </div> <!--fecha a div contornoPostagens-->
        </div><!--fecha a div MeioPostagens-->
        <div class="rodapePostagens">
            <div class="gostei">
                <img class="imgGostei" id="imgGostei" src="_img/thumb52.png" title="" alt=""/>
                <a class="linkGostei" href="" title="">Gostei + [12<?php echo $i ?>]</a>
            </div><!--fecha a div rodapePostagens-->
            <a class="linkComentario" href="" title="">
                <div class="Comentar">Comentar</div><!--fecha a div Comentar-->
            </a>
            <a class="linkComentario" href="" title="">
                <div class="comentarios">Comentários [258]</div><!--fecha a div comentarios-->
            </a>
        </div><!--fecha a div rodapePostagens-->
        <div class="comentarioPost">
            <p class="internoComentario">Eu não gostei do assunto</p>
            <p class="internoComentario">Estou muito feliz de compartilhar meu primeiro anúncio com vocês meus amigos do site Bom Perfil.</p>
            <p class="internoComentario">Estou muito feliz de compartilhar meu primeiro anúncio com vocês meus amigos do site Bom Perfil.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!--fecha a div postagens-->

<?php } while ($exibePostagensAssoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($exibePostagens)); ?>
</br>
</br>
<a href="#buscaProfissional" class="scroll"><img src="_img/walking18.png" title="Voltar ao topo">&nbsp;Voltar ao topo</a></br>
```

Comment: Em que formato recebes isso do servidor? Via AJAX?

Comment: Podes usar outra palavra em vez de "atacar"? não é muito claro o que isso quer dizer... queres dizer apagar, ou selecionar?

Comment: Eu estou precisando dar um display block somente na div darespectiva postagem, é como se fosse uma rede social e cada post tem seus comentários, atualmente eu consigo exibir a div mas acabam todas ficando visiveis, eu preciso exibir somente a div do respectivo post.
Eu estou exibindo por php mesmo usando um laço do While.

No caso preciso exibir somente a div 'comentarioPost' quando eu clicar no link 'comentarioPost' que fica dentro da tag a 'linkComentario'

Comment: Compreendi correto que esses dados **não** vêm por ajax mas sim quando a página carrega? Nesse caso deves resolver isso no lado do servidor. Como é o código no servidor?

Comment: Desta forma eu consigo exibir todas as divs, mas eu queria exibir somente a div filha do post.


   `$(".comentarios").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".comentarioPost").css("display", "block");
    });`

Comment: Bruno, acrescentei suas explicações à pergunta. Em vez colocar isso aqui nos comentários, é só você [edit] a pergunta esclarecendo as dúvidas e depois avisa com um arroba, tipo *"@Sergio, editei a pergunta para responder sua dúvida"*. Você sempre vai receber avisos sobre seus posts, mas para notificar outros usuários precisa do arroba. Você é livre para editar a pergunta sempre que fôr necessário melhorá-la. E bem-vindo ao SOpt!

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia atribuir um data-attribute para ligar cada post à seus comentários. Por exemplo:

```
<a class="linkComentario" href="" title="">
    <div class="comentarios" data-postid="<?= $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>">Comentários [258]</div><!--fecha a div comentarios-->
</a>
<div class="comentarioPost" data-postid="<?= $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>">...</div>
```

E selecionar os comentários assim:

```
$(".comentarios").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.comentarioPost[data-postid="' + $(this).attr('data-postid') + '"]').css("display", "block");
});
```

Não testei, mas creio que funcione.

Comment: Vou testar e te aviso Brendo, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda, e igualmente com o Sergio.

Comment: Não está aceitando a função data-postid Rs está afirmando que a função não é permitida na versão que eu estou usando.

Comment: Qual a versão que você está usando?

Comment: Funcionou assim brother 
$(".postagens .comentarios .linkComentario").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.postagens').find('.comentarioPost').css("display","block");
    });

Obrigado, eu estou usando a 5.6

Comment: Cara, desculpa. Havia esquecido de por o $ antes do nome da variável. Fiz copiando e colando e nem percebi. Tenta de novo.

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei um id a div para ver se ajuda.

Gostei + [12]
            
            
                Comentar

```
        <div class="comentarios" ><a id="<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>" class="linkComentario" href="" title="">Comentários [258]</a></div><!--fecha a div comentarios-->
        </div><!--fecha a div rodapePostagens-->
        <div class="comentarioPost" id="<?php echo $exibePostagensAssoc['id_post'] ?>">
            <p class="internoComentario">Eu não gostei do assunto</p>
            <p class="internoComentario">Estou muito feliz de compartilhar meu primeiro anúncio com vocês meus amigos do site Bom Perfil.</p>
            <p class="internoComentario">Estou muito feliz de compartilhar meu primeiro anúncio com vocês meus amigos do site Bom Perfil.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Funcionou assim pessoal.

$(".postagens .comentarios .linkComentario").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.postagens').find('.comentarioPost').css("display","block");
    });
Obrigado a todos